# Extrude gradually from a uv sphere

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude, proportional-editing

I am trying to model this fella:
[image]

And I am struggling to extrude his eyebrows in this smooth way.
Basically I would wish to extrude the eyebrow in a way that gradually blends into the sphere from the top of the eyebrow like seen in the photo rather than having them pop out of no where.
I have tried to use inset and extrude for this but I am getting the following:

[image]

Is there a way to extrude the eyebrow so it would look like it is bulging more from the bottom and less from the top to give it a look more similar to the original picture?

Comment: I'm not experienced in it so can't post an answer but looks like a job for the Sculpt mode, I'm sure there are many brushes there that could help you out. Tried that?

Comment: did u try to use proportional editing? i think that would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i do think that the best way would be to use a SubD Workflow!

I'll show you how i personally would do this:

1: Add a UV Sphere to you scene

2: Enter Edit Mode

3: Press K to use the Knife tool

4: Cut the rough outlines for the eyebrows

[image]

5: Extrude the new faces outwards

[image]

6: Add a Subdivision Modifier to your Mesh and set the resolution to 3

[image]

7: Enter edit mode again

8: Select the edges that you want to blend into the mesh

[image]

9: Press G two times to slide the edges until its limit

10: Press A to select all and then M - Merge by distance to make the overlapping edges one

11: Now select all the Faces that you want to sharpen

[image]

12: Sharpen them by changing the Mean Crease in the Edges Data.

[image]

13: Now your mesh should look like this. If some areas look to clumpy try the Edge slide (Double G) or just grab and move them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sculpting a heavily subdivided sphere or with [dyntopo](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/dyntopo.html), then [retopologizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retopology) seems like the way to go… However if you want to start with somewhat optimal topology, either rotate the UV sphere so an edge aligns with the brow, cut it in half across X=0 or Y=0 plane, mirror and transfer normal data by interpolated nearest to another hidden sphere, or you can also try starting with an icosphere (this layout of triangles can be found at the top of a default icosphere, I rotated it around Y axis):

[image]

As you see, you don't need to align edges with an equator, because it's trivial to draw a line and separate national colors in a shader:

[image]

Yet another approach is to leave the ball alone and add detail with another overlapping mesh:

[image]

It would make animating it easier…

Answer (score 0):

update:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### [image]

one way is to se proportional editing to do that:

[image]

Comment: I have tried proportional editing, the thing is it doesn't give this sharp "cliff" I wanted at the bottom, I would like it only be proportional from the top.